# Changing Azure AD B2C Access Token lifetime doesn't work

Tags: azure, access-token, azure-ad-b2c

I went to my Azure B2C → User flows (policies) → A flow of type "Sign up and sign in V2" → Properties → Token Lifetime.

There I changed the "Access & ID token lifetimes (minutes)" from 60 to 15. Then I saved. I emptied the cache and refreshed the page to make sure that the value was really modified.

Today, more than 24 hours later, all my access tokens still have a lifetime of 60 minutes. I don't get it. I got the access token directly from a brand new authorization code.

Should I wait longer? Is it a bug in Azure? Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: This reproes on V2 userflows. seems like a bug.

Comment: We have reported it to the engineering team.

Comment: @J-Flex could you please drop a mail to AADB2CPreview@microsoft.com, with your tenant id?

Comment: I have more info about my issue: I get an expiration time of 900 in the http response when retrieving the access token but the expiration time inside the token is still one hour after it was issued.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't reproduce your issue on my side. There is no delay for this change to take effect. Make sure you are using the same application(clientId) to retrieve the access token.

Here are my test steps and results for your reference.

**1.Set the token lifetime to 60 minutes.**

[image]

Get access token by using auth code flow.

**Get auth code.**

```
https://tonyb2ctest.b2clogin.com/tonyb2ctest.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_testsignupin
&client_id=c3a6429c-01XXX-ae02-1579b3f3fa9c
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://windowXXXsbowman.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://tonyb2ctest.onmicrosoft.com/api/user_impersonation
&state=12345
```

**Get access token**

```
https://tonyb2ctest.b2clogin.com/tonyb2ctest.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=B2C_1_testsignupin
```

[image]

**2.Set the token lifetime to 15 minutes.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, I have a weird result: I only looked at the expiration time inside the token ("exp") and it's always one hour from now, but in the response from the http response when I got the token did indeed say 900s like in your screenshot. Is the value of "exp" in you token also 900 seconds from now?

Comment: @JFlex I can reproduce your issue. I have reported it to Azure B2C support team. Will let you know if there is any update.